# How to solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{\ln (x)}{x-1}$ using pre-derivative calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

How can I solve:  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1} \frac{\ln x}{x-1}$$using pre-derivative Calculus (no logarithm series or L'Hôpital's rule)?

Comment: I can't see how this is possible - how do you even know what $\ln x$ means without using calculus?  And if the answer is "the inverse function of $e^x$", how do you know what $e^x$ means without calculus?  Will be very interested to see any answers.

Comment: @David : the question says "pre-derivative calculus" so presumably certain limits may be used (?) as long as they don't require derivatives.  The question seems dicey to me.

Comment: The instructions state in their entirety:  "In Exercises 81-90, use a graphing utility to graph the function and estimate the limit.  Use a table to reinforce your conclusion.  Then find the limit using analytic methods."  The function is given as Lim x->1 Ln x / x - 1.

Comment: @Irongrave : I edited my answer to give an alternate solution.  It does not require derivatives either, but describing it as "pre-derivative calculus" is questionable. Regarding your comments, graphing any function such as  $1/x$ or $\ln x/(x-1)$ using a graphing utility and making a table don't prove anything.

Comment: @Irongrave : Reading the instructions you were provided word-for-word (which you gave in your comment), it looks like they aren't actually asking you to prove anything using pre-derivative calculus.  A graphing utility and a table merely suggest that the limit is $1$ and don't prove anything.  "Analytic methods" could mean anything, including as much calculus as you want.  My answer gives two ways to do a real proof without using derivatives.  I am confident about the second way, but I don't know how to completely justify the first way without using the idea of the derivative.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: set $x=e^y$; if $x\to1$, then $y\to0$. The limit is a fundamental one.

Answer (score 2):

One way (among many) to define $e$ is as the solution of $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^h -1}{h} = 1$.  I don't know how often people do this, but it's true (and it leads to $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$).  Then define $\ln$ as the inverse function to $\exp$, where $\exp(x) \equiv e^x$.  Make the substitution $x=e^y$ in your limit, simplify, and use this definition of $e$.

I don't know offhand how to justify this definition of $e$ without using derivatives.  If you can show there exists $t>0$ satisfying $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{t^h -1}{h} = 1$, then the uniqueness question is easy to solve (and $t=e$).  And if you can show $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2^h -1}{h} > 0$ ("2" is just an arbitrary number greater than $1$), then the existence problem is easy to solve.  That leaves the problem of proving $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2^h -1}{h} > 0$ without using derivatives.  I'm pretty sure it can be done.  I'm also sure someone in MSE knows how.

EDIT: ALTERNATE SOLUTION:  Define $\ln$ by $\ln x = \int_1^x 1/t\,dt$.  This is actually done fairly often.  Defining the definite (Riemann) integral does not require derivatives.  In that sense this solution will be "pre-derivative".  In reality, almost no one or maybe even no one learns about definite integrals before they learn about derivatives, so calling this solution "pre-derivative" is questionable. Anyway, by sketching $y=1/x$ and using the fact that $1/1=1$, you can see that $\ln x \approx x-1$ for $x$ close to $1$.  You can show your limit actually equals $1$ by using the continuity of the function $1/x$ and an epsilon-delta argument.

The definition I give of $e$ in the first solution above is missing from Wikipedia's article on $e$.  I don't know if there is a good mathematical reason for omitting it (a good reason would be if it were impossible to prove $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2^h -1}{h} > 0$ without using derivatives), if it's not popular enough, or if it's just a careless omission.  Wikipedia isn't perfect.

Both solutions to your problem avoids derivatives, but the whole exercise strikes me as artificial.

Comment: Nice one @Stefan, this answers my comment on the OP (+1)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I think some of your explanation is a bit above my head, but it sounds like my book messed up -- it asks us to first find this limit graphically by using a table, then by using analytic methods.  The only solutions I found for the analytic portion were using the Taylor series (Chegg) and L'hopital's Rule (from a Math assistant on CalcChat.com), and we have yet to be introduced to either of these concepts, so I figured I had missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you one more answer. Defining $u = x-1$, your limit becomes:

$$L = \lim_{u\to 0} \frac{\ln{(u+1)}}{u} = 1,$$

since $\ln(u+1)$ behaves like $u$ as $u \to 0$, indeed $\ln(u+1) \sim u$ as $u\to0$.

Cheers!

Comment: How do you know ln(u+1) ~ u, if u close 0? (using pre derivative calculus)