# Limit with natural log in the denominator: $\lim_{x\to1}{\frac{x^2 - 1}{\ln x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

Value of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}{\frac{x^2 - 1}{\ln x}}$

The answer is given to be $2$. I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: rule of de l'Hospital

Comment: This limit might be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648176/how-to-solve-lim-x-rightarrow1-frac-ln-xx-1-using-pre-derivative-cal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since simple substitution of $x:=1$ would yield the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$,

L'Hôpital's rule to the rescue:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

So, take the derivative of the top *and* the bottom (not the derivative of the top *divided* by the bottom).

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^2-1}{\ln x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{2x}{1/x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}2x^2= 2$$

Answer (score 6):

We don't need to rely on L'Hospital's Rule (not that there's anything wrong with using it here).

We only need recall that $\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log x \le x-1$ for $x>0$, with strict inequalities for $x\ne 1$.

Then, for $x> 1$

$$x+1=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}<\frac{x^2-1}{\log x}<\frac{x^2-1}{\frac{x-1}{x}}=x(x+1)$$

By the squeeze theorem, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1^+}\frac{x^2-1}{\log x}=2\tag1$$

An analogous development shows for $0<x<1$ that

$$x+1=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}>\frac{x^2-1}{\log x}>\frac{x^2-1}{\frac{x-1}{x}}=x(x+1)$$

whereby the squeeze theorem, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x^2-1}{\log x}=2\tag2$$

Putting together $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{\log x}=2$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: I love your "as was to be shown." It's very Euclid-esque. :D

Comment: Very elegant proof, I might add.

Comment: @AdamHrankowski Thank you!!  I really appreciate the comment!

Comment: Those inequalities should be $\leq$ rather than $<$, since all three terms are equal at $x=1$. (or clarify that they were only meant to hold for $x \neq 1$)

Comment: Some links to post about the inequality used in your answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161278/show-that-if-1-x0-then-x-1-%E2%89%A5-lnx-%E2%89%A5-1%E2%88%921-x

Comment: @martinsleziak  Thanks!  +1 for the useful comment!

Comment: @hurkyl This was tacitly assumed and even referenced in the sentence following the inequalities.  But, I edited under your suggestion for clarity and precision.   Thank you for the useful comment.

Answer (score 3):

**They told us not to use l'Hospital if not 100% sure.**
So for beginners with a little bit of stamina this is a nice method.
You can directly reduce the diverging factor here.
Recall
$$\ln(x) = \ln ((x-1)+1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^n,$$
therefore
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 } \frac {  x ^2 -1 }{ \ln ( x)  }=\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac{  (x+1)(x-1) }{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^n }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac{  (x+1)}{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^{n-1} }  } .  $$

By shifting the index we get
$$ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac{  (x+1)}{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(x-1)^{n-1} }  } = \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac{  (x+1)}{ \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i+1}(x-1)^{i} }  }  .$$
Since

$$ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i+1}(x-1)^{i} }  = 1,$$
we have
$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac{  (x+1)}{ \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i+1}(x-1)^{i} }  } ={ \frac{\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }  (x+1)}{\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 } \sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i+2}}{i+1}(x-1)^{i} }  } =\frac{2}{1}=2.$$

Comment: (+1) I think series solutions are often much more insightful about the behavior of a function than L'Hopital is. Maybe easier to let $y=x-1$, and take the limit as $y \to 0$. Then you can just use the expansion of $\ln (1+y)$.

Comment: You can simplify by using a taylor series with remainder rather than the full series: $\log(1+x) = x + x h(x)$, where $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

As the function is of form $\frac{0}{0}$ we can apply LHR

therefore the derivative of function becomes $\frac{2x}{\frac{1}{x}}$

which is equal to

> $2x^2$

now you know $x\to1$

Comment: It seems misleading to say "the function becomes" this other expression. It makes it sound as if it's the same function, rather than a function with the same _limit_. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @ Michael is it ok now

Comment: The newly edited version seems misleading in a different way.  "the derivative becomes${}\,\ldots$ makes it sound as if that is $\dfrac d {dx}\, \dfrac{x^2-1}{\log x}$.  But what you've done is to take the derivative of the numerator and the denominator separately, not the derivative of the quotient. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : $$\frac{x^2-1}{\log x} = \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{\log x}= \frac{x+1}{\frac{\log x}{x-1}}$$

And recall [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Logarithmic_and_exponential_functions).

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { { x }^{ 2 }-1 }{ \ln { x }  } =\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { x+1 }{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ x-1 }  }  }  } =\frac { \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \left( x+1 \right)  }  }{ \lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \left( \frac { \ln { x }  }{ x-1 }  \right)  }  } =2$$

Comment: Is there a simple proof that $\lim_{x \to 1}\ln(x)/(x-1)=1$ or are you relying on l'hopital

Comment: Your have 0/0 in the denominator.

Comment: $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 1 }{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ x-1 }  } \\ t=\ln { x\quad \Rightarrow x={ e }^{ t } } \\ x\rightarrow 1,t\rightarrow 0\\ \lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { t }{ { e }^{ t }-1 } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { 1 }{ \frac { { e }^{ t }-1 }{ t }  }  } =1 } $$ and see here :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/proof-of-fx-ex-1-x-1-text-as-x-to-0-using-epsilon-delta-definiti